# Datalogic Barcode/Weight Scanner

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-scanner

Could anyone please give me any idea as to where to start my coding in order to get data from OPOS(Datalogic Magellan device) weighting and barcode scanning in C#?? For example, what library and what function I should be using for this case. I am clueless as I have already spent numerous of hours searching for an answer online. Not even came close online.

I don't know any api that I can use to get the weight and barcode for the usb device into my C# program.

I am currently using Datalogic scale. I tried the build-in windows reader but it didn't read in any data from the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I used the `Microsoft.PointOfService` library which can directly create connection to most of the opos base machine. And make sure you have your Logical Device Name right! Very Very important. This is NOT any normal name you found in your regedit, it MUST be define manually by yourself inside the opos adk program that you installed along with the opos machine.

Then you can pass in the name as usual in your C# program.

For example: you set USB_Scale as your logical device name inside OPOS program
in C#

```
this.myDevice = explore.GetDevice("Scale", "USB_Scale");
```

Note: Make sure you set claim to 1000; It might not work if you didn't do so.
Also : `this.myScale = ((Scale)explore.CreateInstance(myDevice));` <- this might help~

The rest is just straight forward.